# Setting Code Coverage percentage in build.yml

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a requirement of settings code coverage percentage for my unit test cases running in VSTS through the build.yml file.

Right now the build is passing for any code coverage percentage that's coming. I want to restrict this and fail the build if the percentage is not 70%.

Can you help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to publish the test results (and code coverage is in that) and then use another task or release gate to check those results. You can do this with SonarQube Quality gate (needs a SonarQube server) or you can try the marketplace.

For example this task: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mspremier.BuildQualityChecks

You can also check it yourself (using PowerShell for example) via the API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/vsts/test/code%20coverage?view=vsts-rest-5.0